# Gnome-Terminal Linux Script

Tags: linux, bash, gnome, gnome-terminal

I am trying to write a basic write for Linux that opens a terminal window, sends a command, and then sends a character such as "Y" or "N".  Also, after a fixed period of time, stop the process.

So far I can get the window and command running using:

```
gnome-terminal -e "command"
```

Anyone know how I can send a character like "Y" after that command executes in the new terminal window as well as stop the process in that window after a fixed period of time?

Comment: hope this help. [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5363/how-to-start-a-terminal-with-certain-text-already-input-on-the-command-line).  you can create an executable file which contains necessary logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your executable file which allow to send a character into new window terminal.

example `yourexecutable.sh` (refer to @ændrük [example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5363/how-to-start-a-terminal-with-certain-text-already-input-on-the-command-line)):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# Get a Bash shell
spawn -noecho bash

# Wait for a prompt
expect "$ "

# Type something
send "my text to be posted"

# Hand over control to the user
interact

exit
```

then by using `timeout` command run this command

```
gnome-terminal -e "timeout 10 ~/yourexecutable.sh"
```

Comment: Thank you bekt!  The timeout and expect commands are exactly what I needed!